# Dynamic define database in Sequelize for multi-tenant support return wrong query syntax

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js, multi-tenant

I'm Working on Multi-tenant Application (SAAS) with Shared Database Isolated Schema principle.

I've tried solution from https://github.com/renatoargh/data-isolation-example

from this article https://renatoargh.wordpress.com/2018/01/10/logical-data-isolation-for-multi-tenant-architecture-using-node-express-and-sequelize/

This is My Sequelize Model using schema Option

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Task = sequelize.define('Task', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      field: 'Id'
    },

    description: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
      allowNull: false,
      field: 'Description'
    },

    done: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      default: false,
      field: 'Done'
    },

    taskTypeId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      field: 'TaskTypeId'
    },

    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true,
      field: 'UserId'
    }
  }, {
      freezeTableName: true,
      tableName: 'Tasks',
      createdAt: false,
      updatedAt: false
    })
  Task.changeSchema = schema => Task.schema(schema)
  Task.associate = models => {
    Task.belongsTo(models.TaskType, {
      as: 'taskType',
      foreignKey: 'taskTypeId'
    })
  }


  return Task
}
```

And Stop at this problem

```
SELECT
  `Task`.`Id`              AS `id`,
  `Task`.`Description`     AS `description`,
  `Task`.`Done`            AS `done`,
  `Task`.`TaskTypeId`      AS `taskTypeId`,
  `Task`.`UserId`          AS `userId`,
  `taskType`.`Id`          AS `taskType.id`,
  `taskType`.`Description` AS `taskType.description`
FROM `tenant_1.Tasks` AS `Task` LEFT OUTER JOIN `shared.TaskTypes` AS `taskType`
    ON `Task`.`TaskTypeId` = `taskType`.`Id`
WHERE `Task`.`UserId` = 1;
```

as you see, **FROM `tenant_1.Tasks`** in mysql is a wrong syntax. it must be **FROM `tenant_1`.`Tasks`**

how to change **`tenant_1.Tasks`** to **`tenant_1`.`Tasks`**

Comment: how about if you use directly from FROM `tenant_1.Tasks` to `Tasks`

Comment: it works, but i want it can be dynamicly change to `tenant_1`.`Tasks`, `tenant_2`.`Tasks`, `tenant_3`.`Tasks`

Comment: It seems like you need to use `Execute` command see this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: How to use it in sequelize ?

Comment: I am not a sequelize expert just need to ask about this `tenant_1` is your Databasename?

Comment: yes, `tenant_1` is my database name

Comment: My suggestion is just change the connection of database working with the data expected.

Comment: so is it possible if 1 app, can dynamically change between database ?
something like this
http://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-multi-tenant/en/latest/shared-database-isolated-schema.html

Comment: Nothing is impossible. just explore yourself.

Comment: `<snide-remark>`Sometimes 3rd party packages are more trouble than benefit.`</snide-remark>`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MySQL? If so, that is the expected behavior.

From the [documentation](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-schema) of **Model.schema**:

> Apply a schema to this model. For postgres, this will actually place the schema in front of the table name - `"schema"."tableName"`, while the schema will be prepended to the table name for mysql and sqlite - `'schema.tablename'`.